# Devise login doesn't work / no error messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Guys i've looked everywhere to fix this issue but I'm out of luck.

I got a devise login system and i signed up an account admin@admin.com in development and on the log i got the confirmation email and i went to that email and so my account got confirmed. Now when i try to login the console gives me this message:

```
Started GET "/users/sign_in?utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=iHIEXxGHWaIdtAGhcZ7EKvEEEYGmoEfgr1K8NcKb9nFIXuD6dpMVimOO6aBEdZJUWv9Irt%2FT0vnaucjW%2BgmJQQ%3D%3D&user%5Bemail%5D=admin%40admin.com&user%5Bpassword%5D=[FILTERED]&user%5Bremember_me%5D=0&commit=Log+in" for ::1 at 2016-06-01 13:11:54 +0200
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"iHIEXxGHWaIdtAGhcZ7EKvEEEYGmoEfgr1K8NcKb9nFIXuD6dpMVimOO6aBEdZJUWv9Irt/T0vnaucjW+gmJQQ==", "user"=>{"email"=>"admin@admin.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Log in"}
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (3.7ms)
  Rendered partials/_header.html.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered partials/_menu.html.erb (0.2ms)
  Rendered shared/_breadcrumbs.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered partials/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered partials/_javascripts.html.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 143ms (Views: 52.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

After this the page just refreshes and i'm not logged in.
When i go to resend confirmation instructions it says 'email is already confirmed, try signing in'

My sign in form looks like this:

```
<% provide(:title, "Sign in") %>
<div class="col-md-12">
  <form class="sign-box">
    <header class="sign-title"> Sign in </header>

    <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>

        <% if devise_error_messages!.present? %>
            <div class="alert alert-warning alert-icon alert-close alert-dismissable fade in" role="alert">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
              <i class="font-icon font-icon-warning"></i>
              <%= devise_error_messages! %>
            </div>
        <% end %>

      <div class="field form-group">
        <%= f.label :email, class: 'float-left' %><br />
        <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control', autofocus: true %>
      </div>

      <div class="field form-group">
        <%= f.label :password, class: 'float-left' %><%= link_to 'Forgot your password?', new_user_password_path, class: 'float-right reset' %>
        <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control', autocomplete: "off" %>
      </div>

      <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
        <div class="field form-group">
          <div class="checkbox float-left">
            <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
            <%= f.label :remember_me %>
          </div>
        </div>
      <% end -%>

      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Log in", class: 'btn btn-rounded' %>
      </div>

        <p class="sign-note">New to our website? <%= link_to "Sign Up", new_user_registration_path %></p>
    <% end %>
  </form>
</div>
```

What could it be guys? I'm out of options after trying for days.

Comment: is that server information given after you click login button?

Comment: Yes the message is from after clicking the login button

Comment: what is the value of  url: session_path(resource_name)   ?

Comment: the value is :user , the same name as the model which is automatically created by devise.

Comment: I meant what is the path of url, not the resource name

Comment: path: new_user_session, verb: GET,  url:  /users/sign_in(.:format)          , controller action: devise/sessions#new

Comment: when rendered it looks like : <form class="new_user" id="new_user" action="/users/sign_in" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="P5NdpCBLkJPXFeSE098P3pQKzoz4olaz2TpkvRTaMGr/v7kBR1/cu6kvDIXmNFmgP/GXo4HRw6qs0RBeLEhPWg==" />

Comment: ath: new_user_session, verb: GET  <--is this the path set on the submit form ? it should not be like that.

Comment: I understand your point, and it seems like thats indeed the cause of the problem but how do i change the get to post. I've only been using the default devise paths. I tried creating a create.html.erb file in the devise/sessions folder and i edited the link to the login page to user_session_path but its still not working and its still processing a get method.

Comment: i have updated my answer, can you find out wether it helps?

Comment: Hmm no it still gives the same error. and it is : Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML

Comment: then explicitly tell the post method like this , form_for( :user, url: user_session_path, method: :post) do |f|

Comment: if that dosent work try restarting server. as you may already have logged in.

Comment: still no luck mate. It goes wrong when i enter the page, before even submitting, it says: Started GET "/users/sign_in" for ::1 at 2016-06-01 14:32:08 +0200
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML

Comment: please check the rails console. user has sign_in_count filed. if that is 0 then you havenot logged in. But if that number>0 then you have successfully logged in.

Comment: that is perfectly normal. before submitting, there is always almost Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML.  this is saying that you have clicked login button and the login form is rendered. main thing is what it says after submitting.

Comment: Oké what i did was, delete the new.html.erb (which was automatically created by devise:views) and i made a create.html.erb with the same layout. Now when i go to sign_in it gives me the standard devise layout and when i fill in my information it brings me to my custom layout and when i fill my information again it suddenly works. I'm logged in. but how do i get to my custom layout instantly .... this is stressing me out, one error after the other.

Comment: new.html.erb is where you keep your form.  create.html.erb is not needed here.    when the action new gets hit, it render the new.html.erb. after submitting this form, it will go the devise session controller create action. it is all in the form url

Comment: try a fresh project. follow this post http://guides.railsgirls.com/devise

Comment: remember failure is what teaches us. its frustating, but it will pay its worth. happy coding.   also dont forget to update this post , if you manage to solve this problem. you are already one step closer.

Comment: I fixed the issue and posted the answer.. thanks for all your help i really appreciated it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer was rather simple all along

I had to change `<form class="sign-box">` to `<div class="sign-box">`
cause apparently you can't have a ruby form_for tag inside a html form attribute.

Answer (score 1):

if that response from server is given after you submit the form,
then you have messed up something. check your routes.

when we submit the login form, server should show

```
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
```

also, when the form is submited the request is in POST like below

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for ::1 at 2016-06-01 17:11:36 +0545
```

but your server is sending a Get request.

```
Started GET "/users/sign_in?utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticit...
```

> path: new_user_session, verb: GET, url: /users/sign_in(.:format)

the path should be `user_session_path` with verb POST

**update**: 
try this and see what happens.

```
form_for( :user, url: user_session_path) do |f|
```

**update2:**
also I have found that if you are already logged in, and still  try to log in again without logout, it is again redirected to SessionsController#new. try restarting your server and observe the server during the first login.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<%= button_to "Sign in", new_user_session_path %>
```

to

```
<%= button_to "Sign in", new_user_session_path, method: :get %>
```